# How to add "Editable Web sites?"

Tags: experience-manager, cme, configuration, 2013

In SDL Tridion 2013's `Dashboard` (formerly `Tridion`) tab, there's a section for `Editable Web sites.`

Are these Experience Manager (staging) sites? I can see and follow the steps to *enable* Experience Manager, but what controls which urls display here?

**Edit**: In 2011 and 2013, there's a commented-out section in the CME.config that has:

```
<!--
Uncomment the following block to add a thumbnail for SE enabled website 
As an url you must set the SE enabled website's url.
The thumbnail image should be 32x32 pixels size and should be placed in 
/Styles/Thumbnails folder.
            -->
<!--thumbnails>
    <thumbnail url="http://[se_enabled_website]">thumbnail.png</thumbnail>
</thumbnails-->
```

Not sure if this is specific to 2011 or 2013, though. Updating the url doesn't change the list of Editable Web sites for me. Tips of formatting or if this applies to SE or XPM appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an outdated feature, for previous versions of SiteEdit (2009).

It is looking in the old "`Web.Config`" of the SiteEdit directory for the node:

```
/cfg:configuration/cfg:siteMappings/cfg:siteMapping/@proxyPattern
```

But I don't think it is prepared for the new Experience Manager.

Comment: Interesting, I guess I was assuming the change from "SDL Tridion *SiteEdit*-enabled Web sites" to just "*Editable* Web sites" meant this section was changed. Maybe I'll have to install SE 2009 to confirm? ;-)